# Supremum Question

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Give an example of each of the following, or state that the request is impossible.

(a) a set $B$ with inf $B$ $\geq$ sup $B$

(b) a finite set that contains its infimum but not its supremum

(c) A bounded subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ that contains its supremum but not its infimum

For (a), I feel like $B=\{1\}$? I could be wrong.

For (b) I have $[0,1\}$

For (c) I am unsure of a set that satisfies this condition.

Comment: I eddited my answer (after you eddited your question).

Answer (score 1):

a) and b) look good, if you mean $[0,1)$ in b). By the way, when $B=\{1\}$, we have
$$\min B = \inf B = \sup B = \max B.$$

For c) you could consider the set
$$ Q= \{ q\in \mathbf Q \mid -\sqrt 2 < q \leq 1 \}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for example the set of the non-negative real numbers.